# Django ORM make Union Query with column not in common in both tables, set value of not in common column as null

Tags: django, union, django-orm

Hi i want to make a query in Djang ORM
like this

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Null as Col4, Null as Col5 from Table2
```

as you see Col4, Col5 are not in common but they will return null instead in Table2.

```
Table1_qs = Table1.objects.all()
Table2_qs = Table2.objects.all()

Table1_qs.values('Col1', 'Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5').union(Table2_qs.values('Col1', 'Col2','Col3','Null as Col4','Null as Col5'))
```

How can i make the query in Django?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is made possible by Value and annotate.
here is how.

let say Col4 is type IntegerField,
and Col5 is type CharField

```
   from django.db.models import Value, IntegerField, CharField
    
    Table1_qs = Table1.objects.all()
    Table2_qs = Table2.objects.all()
    
    Table1_qs = Table1_qs.values('Col1', 'Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5')
    Table2_qs = Table2_qs.values('Col1', 'Col2','Col3').annotate(
            Col4=Value(None, output_field=IntegerField()), 
            Col5=Value(None, output_field=CharField()) )
    
    unioned_query = Table1_qs.union(Table2_qs)
```

please note:

- 1: columns type must be the same as each.
- 2: and they must be in same order as well.

the problem that arise is within foreign-key. as only the id (primary key) of them will be returned when using Values() on a query-set!

I hope Django add a way to get them as usual objects too.